# unable to apply search on multiple fields Django

Tags: python, django

```
def search(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    srch = request.POST['title']
    if srch:
      match = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=srch,email__icontains=srch)
      # match = Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'email'),).filter(search=srch)
      if match:
        return render(request,'post/index.html',{'sr':match})
      else:
        messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,' No result found ')
    else:
      return redirect('post')
  return render(request,"post/index.html")
```

Comment: here is problem (match=Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=srch,email__icontains=srch))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [OR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#or) condition

```
match = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=srch) | Q(email__icontains=srch))
```

For [AND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#and) condion

```
match = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=srch) & Q(email__icontains=srch))
```

I think it's better use `GET` request instead of `POST` request for searching.

Comment: there is an Error [name 'Q' is not defined]

Comment: @JeffVipul you need to import Q `from django.db.models import Q`